# Dataframe column status

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

On the column for `status`

[image]

I want set `status` as `1` if diff is less than `0` and `1` if is more than `1`.

Comment: What do you want to use if `diff` is between 0 and 1?

Comment: put code so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to choose `1` or `''` depending on the condition.

**Use this:**

```
import numpy as np

df_small["status"] = np.where((df_small["diff"] < 0) | (df_small["diff"] > 1), 1, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` or, if you prefer, you can simply apply a lambda function like this:

```py
df['status'] = df['diff'].apply(lambda val: 1 if val < 0 or val > 1 else np.nan)
```

As default value you can use `np.nan` or any other value that you like.